# Comparator: Method references not supported at this language level?

Tags: java, java-8, java-7, comparator, method-reference

I wrote the following line of code for a `Java 8` project:

```
Comparator<Person> oldestPerson= Comparator.comparing(Person::getOldestBirthday);
```

It is a simple comparator, however I am trying to use this code In a project that only uses `Java 7`, therefore giving this error:

```
"Method references are not supported at this language level"
```

I understand im getting the error as im not using Java 8. Is there a simple way to re-write the logic without having to use a method reference?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "simple". It's a lot of boilerplate, which is precisely why this was developed.

Comment: Can you please give an example of how it would be done? Or a link?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Comparator<Person> comparator = new Comparator<Person>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Person p1, Person p2) {
        return p1.getOldestBirthday().compareTo(p2.getOldestBirthday());
    }
};
```

This is probably the simplest way to do it in Java 7

Comment: ok so what is there are multiple persons that need to be compared? Rather than just 2 (i.e. p1 and p2)?

Comment: Comparators  basically define how objects of a same type should be ordered.  if you want to apply it to a collection of persons  eg. List<Person> personList, then you can order them using the comparator : Collections.sort(personList, comparator).

Comment: I mean is there a way to sort on multiple clauses i.e. similar to the .thenComparing() method in Java 8?